# Bad Allocation while trying to create USRP Object in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, usrp, uhd

I'm getting an error - **"bad allocation**" while working with the UHD library.

I'm trying to compile some basic code to learn more about the UHD library. After compiling the program I'm getting an error.

Code:

```
int UHD_SAFE_MAIN(int argc, char *argv[]) {
uhd::set_thread_priority_safe();

std::string device_args("addr=192.168.10.2");
std::string subdev("A:0");
std::string ant("TX/RX");
std::string ref("internal");

double rate(1e6);
double freq(915e6);
double gain(10);
double bw(1e6);

//create a usrp device
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << boost::format("Creating the usrp device with: %s...") %device_args << std::endl;
uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::sptr usrp = uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::make(device_args);


// Lock mboard clocks
std::cout << boost::format("Lock mboard clocks: %f") % ref << std::endl;
usrp->set_clock_source(ref);

//always select the subdevice first, the channel mapping affects the other settings
std::cout << boost::format("subdev set to: %f") % subdev << std::endl;
usrp->set_rx_subdev_spec(subdev);
std::cout << boost::format("Using Device: %s") % usrp->get_pp_string() << std::endl;

//set the sample rate
if (rate <= 0.0) {
    std::cerr << "Please specify a valid sample rate" << std::endl;
    return ~0;
}

// set sample rate
std::cout << boost::format("Setting RX Rate: %f Msps...") % (rate / 1e6) << std::endl;
usrp->set_rx_rate(rate);
std::cout << boost::format("Actual RX Rate: %f Msps...") % (usrp->get_rx_rate() / 1e6) << std::endl << std::endl;

// set freq
std::cout << boost::format("Setting RX Freq: %f MHz...") % (freq / 1e6) << std::endl;
uhd::tune_request_t tune_request(freq);
usrp->set_rx_freq(tune_request);
std::cout << boost::format("Actual RX Freq: %f MHz...") % (usrp->get_rx_freq() / 1e6) << std::endl << std::endl;

// set the rf gain
std::cout << boost::format("Setting RX Gain: %f dB...") % gain << std::endl;
usrp->set_rx_gain(gain);
std::cout << boost::format("Actual RX Gain: %f dB...") % usrp->get_rx_gain() << std::endl << std::endl;

// set the IF filter bandwidth
std::cout << boost::format("Setting RX Bandwidth: %f MHz...") % (bw / 1e6) << std::endl;
usrp->set_rx_bandwidth(bw);
std::cout << boost::format("Actual RX Bandwidth: %f MHz...") % (usrp->get_rx_bandwidth() / 1e6) << std::endl << std::endl;

// set the antenna
std::cout << boost::format("Setting RX Antenna: %s") % ant << std::endl;
usrp->set_rx_antenna(ant);
std::cout << boost::format("Actual RX Antenna: %s") % usrp->get_rx_antenna() << std::endl << std::endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

}

Part of the code where the error occurs:

```
//create a usrp device
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << boost::format("Creating the usrp device with: %s...") %device_args << std::endl;
uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::sptr usrp = uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::make(device_args);
```

Error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzjIL.png)

I'm using:

- Microsoft Visual C++ Express 2010
- C++ language
- UHD library, Win32_VS2010.exe, 003.007.003-release
- Boost library 1_63_0
- I do not connect any URSP device to my computer.

I don't know if the error is connected with UHD library or with the C++ language. I was trying to compile this program using different versions of Microsoft Visual Studio and different versions of the UHD library, including the latest one. I was even trying to compile this on different PC, but the result was similar, there wasn't an error which interrupted the program but i got string "error: bad allocation" in the console instead and program stopped working in the same spot.

When i first started compiling this program I didn't got "bad allocation error" (**UHD_003.004.000 - release**). I got an error which said - "**Error: LookupError: KeyError: No device found for ----->**. After that i decided to upgrade my UHD library version to the newer one (003.007.003) and then **bad allocation error** started occuring. I was trying to install back the previous version but it didn't help.

I was trying to change **type** of device_args, from *string* to *uhd::device_addr_t*, like it is said in manual on http://files.ettus.com/manual, but the error didn't disappear.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same error, did you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

"I do not connect any URSP device to my computer."

You cannot execute this code without having a USRP connected to the computer you are running it on.

when you call uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::make(device_args);
the uhd is trying to connected to a USRP with the IP address you have speciified in device args.

try connecting a usrp to your computer and try again